# Blazor : System.InvalidOperationException: 'RemoteNavigationManager' has not been initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm using Blazor Server on a ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 website for some components that need Blazor power.
Everything works fine, however, I'm not able to navigate from a Blazor component to an ASP.NET MVC route.

For navigation, I've set the following property :

```
[Inject]
public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
```

When I call `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/games/details/" + gameId, true)`, I have the following error :

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'RemoteNavigationManager' has
>   not been initialized.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.AssertInitialized() 
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.NavigateTo(String
>   uri, Boolean forceLoad)    at
>   MyWebSite.Web.Pages.Search.SearchBar.GoToGamePage(Int32 gameId) in
>   D:\repos\MyWebSite\src\MyWebSite.Web\Pages\Search\SearchBar.razor.cs:line
>   58    at
>   MyWebSite.Web.Pages.Search.SearchBar.<>c__DisplayClass47_0.b__5()
>   in
>   D:\repos\MyWebSite\src\MyWebSite.Web\Pages\Search\SearchBar.razor:line
>   22    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallbackWorkItem.InvokeAsync[T](MulticastDelegate
>   delegate, T arg)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem
>   callback, Object arg)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.DispatchEventAsync(UInt64
>   eventHandlerId, EventFieldInfo fieldInfo, EventArgs eventArgs)

Everything I found about NavigationManager is for Blazor web projects, not ASP.NET Core MVC with Blazor components.

Comment: are you injecting it?

Comment: I am, with the [Inject] attribute

Comment: Are you for any chance using `LightInject`?

Comment: Nope, using Autofac actually

Comment: It might be useful to note that `NavigationManager` only works in a Blazor component. It does not work in a `.cshtml` page. You can use `Response.Redirect("/games/details" + gameId);` instead.

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833663/2440

Answer (score -3):

Insert this at the top of your `.razor` file:

```
@inject NavigationManager navigationmanager
```

and then you can say

```
navigationmanager.NavigateTo("/games/details/" + gameId, true)
```

Comment: Is that not doing the same thing?