# How to configure HttpClient base address in Blazor Server using IHttpClientFactory

Tags: .net-core, blazor, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-server-side, httpclientfactory

I am trying to configure `HttpClient` 's base address in a `Blazor` Server using `IHttpClientFactory` but I am getting a runtime exception:

```
    services.AddHttpClient("ApiClient", (provider, client) =>
    {
        var uriHelper = provider.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri);
    });
```

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager' from root provider.'
```

[image: Exception screenshot]

Anyone know what might be the issue here?

Comment: Is `NavigationManager` registered with the DI container?

Comment: I think the runtime is making sure `NavigationManager` is present in DI. 

For Blazor Wasm `builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ApiClient", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));` just works.

Comment: This should work fine in 3.x . Are you using version 5.x

Comment: Yes, I am using 5.0-preview8, but I tested it with 3.1 and got the same result.

Comment: @Mihaimyh I think we need to see more of your code I pasted your code into a new .net5.x and it worked fine as enet suggested. The NavigationManager is provided.

Comment: @Orak This is really strange, I've added a screenshot though. I will investigate this further.

Comment: I can see the error now when I try to create an instance of the httpClient. clientFactory.CreateClient("ApiClient").BaseAddress

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The base url is not available during `ConfigureServices` you can pass it or create a service :

```
services.AddHttpClient();
services.AddTransient<ApiService>();
```

The service:

```
public class ApiService
{
    public ApiService(HttpClient httpClient, NavigationManager navigationManager)
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient;
        NavigationManager = navigationManager;
        HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(NavigationManager.BaseUri);
    }

    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; }
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; }
}
```

A component:

```
   Base Address : @ApiService.HttpClient.BaseAddress
        
    @code {
        [Inject]
        public ApiService ApiService { get; set; }   
        
    }
```

Comment: This was the solution for me. Specifically the way you set BaseAddress here is what I needed. Thanks for posting!!

Comment: How is the base address configured here?

Comment: @Pawel it comes from the Injected service `NavigationManager` property `NavigationManager.BaseUri` wich is the runtime base address. It is being injected into the constructor of the `ApiService`

Comment: Thank you Brian. I need to wrap my head around it. I'm guessing it is the same address as the application host it runs on thus cannot be changed? I'm looking for a solution where it could be read from appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json etc., used to configure HttpClient and that HttpClient injected to service or something in this fashion

Comment: @Pawel This is how you could load it from `AppSettings.json` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71402859/1492496

Comment: Hi @BrianParker, thank-you, this is educational and nearly worked for me. It works great in Visual Studio, but when deployed in IIS on a production server, although the httpclient base address is http://localhost/AppName as expected, I then try GetASync('api/endpoint') AppName appears to be removed and port 80 added, yielding this : http://localhost:80/api/endpoint, which fails (I expected it to go to http://localhost/AppName/api/endpoint, which works from the browser address bar). Any idea what I am overlooking?

Comment: Sorry! I figured it out. I was saying GetASync('/api/Endpoint') with a deadly leading '/'. which worked in VS because there is no "AppName" part but failed in IIS I guess because it was appending my endpoint to the "root" (i.e. localhost:80 without "AppName"). When I removed the offending leading '/' it worked.

Comment: @Peter did you also set the base path? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-base-path

Answer (score 2):

Great answer John. This is the same solution but simpler:

```
services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient 
    { 
        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7110/") 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the services:

```
    var baseAddress = "http://address-goes-here/";
    services.AddScoped(sp =>
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        return client;
    });
```