# http calls in blazor interactiveauto rendermode refreshes run twice

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

When using `RenderMode.InteractiveAuto` in the new .NET8 RC2. When trying to make HTTP calls the page reloads after under 1second and I can't figure out why.

The example code I'm using was from https://github.com/SpaceShot/InteractiveAutoSample/tree/main

Uncommenting the last line in *Home.razor*

`<WebScrape></WebScrape>`

And changing the last line in WebScrape.razor to have the full URL rather than a relative path:

`var response = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<string>("https://localhost:7202/webscraper/bing"); // change port here to the hosted port`

Page loads, displays the html string from the Http call and then displays Loading... and then displays the Html string again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `data-permanent` to the containing div. To preserve the state between renders.

```html
<div style="border : solid; border-color : black; padding: 4px;" data-permanent>
    @Text
</div>
```

The other issue is the component renders twice. Once on the server for prerendering the default (controlled by the containing pages' rendermode) then and once for the `RenderMode` active (initial view ServerSide subsequent views WASM) so the injection for the http client has to be set up on both.

All 3 interactive modes have a parameter `prerender` that is defaulted to true.

You can do this:

```html
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveAuto(prerender: false)]
```

This answer may help with the server base address: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833663/1492496

Comment: `prerender: false` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

InteractiveAuto will first try to load using InteractiveServer (SSR) (ie. the first load) and then will follow with WASM (Client Side Rendering CSR) once the Blazor Bundle is downloaded (ie. the second load).

Try this link for the official explanation [ASP.NET Core Blazor render modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#render-modes)